# How to make a polymer paper-card grow to fit its container?

Tags: html, css, polymer, flexbox

I've got a flexbox container with a two column setup, where the columns are identical height. The divs work just fine, I can see their background colors lining up correctly.

However, when I put a paper-card in each column the cards don't fill the space - so if the left card is longer than the right card, I see background color in the space below the right card.

When try to set height: 100%, the card gets super long and pushes the whole page down.

If I hard-code the height of the container to 500px, this works, but I'd rather not do that. How can I just have the cards fill their columns, which are already matching in height to the length of the longest card?

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">

  :host {
    display: block;
  }

.twocols{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background: lightblue;
      }

.col1{
        width: 50%;
        background: black;
      }

.col2{
        width: 50%;
        background: orange;
      }
</style>

<div class="twocols">

  <div class="col1">
    <paper-card heading="Hello1" style="width: 100%">
      <paper-item><paper-item-body><div>Hi there</div></paper-item-body></paper-item>
    </paper-card>
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <paper-card heading="Hello" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></paper-card>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bBQYVK?editors=1010)

Comment: Oh many Tony19 you're right... what could possibly be making the cards grow so long when I do height: 100%? It must be somewhere else in the code

Comment: Actually I made a fresh html file that only includes what we pasted into codepen, and the issue is still there. I tried it in chrome and safari. What can I do next?

Answer (score 3):

The polymer elements themselves that contain the cards need to have their displays set to flex.

Without the :host{display: flex;} line, the cards would not auto grow to fill their containers. And for some reason I still don't know, setting height: 100% would cause the card to grow way too big. Flex saved the day.

Note that I made custom elements that are just paper-cards that have data coming in and functions to handle and display the data in the cards.

The most important parts are here:

```
<dom-module id="vehicle-info">
  <template>
    <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
      :host{
        display: flex;
      }
      paper-card {
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
...
```

And here:

```
<div class="twocols">      
        <div class="col1">
          <vehicle-info style="width: 100%;" data={{data.vehicleData}}></vehicle-info>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <customer-info style="width: 100%;" data={{data.customerData}}></customer-info>
        </div>  
      </div>
```

So now each column is 50% width, each element is 100% of the width of its column, and it will stretch(flex) to the bottom, and each paper-card will be 100% width of its custom element.